# OverlapSphere centering incorrectly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collider

I am attempting to use an overlapSphere to determine whether a tile within a tile map contains a game object. Then, if the tile is not already occupied, a new game object will be spawned in that tile (if certain other conditions are met). I'm trying to prevent game objects from overlapping with one another. However, I am having trouble centering the spheres about the right location.

```
for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                Vector3 tilePos = tileMap.GetCellCenterWorld(new Vector3Int(x, y, 0));
                if (terrainMap[x, y] == blocked)
                {
                    bool spawn = detectOverlap(tilePos, obstCheckRad);
                    if (spawn)
                    {
                        GameObject obstacle = Instantiate(obstaclePrefab) as GameObject;
                        obstacle.transform.position = tilePos;
                        obstacle.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, (Random.Range(0, 359)));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public bool detectOverlap (Vector3 center, float radius)
    {
        Collider[] collider = Physics.OverlapSphere(center, radius);
        if (collider.Length == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I am using "GetCellCenterWorld" to as the center of my overlapSpheres, however they always seem to originate in the bottom left corner of the map, causing this region of the map to be completely empty, and objects elswhere in the map to still overlap with one another. (see image)

[image: The end result of using my current implementation. I have made the collider radius much larger than intended in order to make the issue easier to see]

My confusion is based around the fact that I am using the same vector3 (tilePos) to place down the game objects. The objects are all moved to the correct position, however, the overlapSpheres all stay at the bottom left.

Comment: 'if (collider.Length <= 1)'? Are you instantiating objects when there is 1 or 0 colliders? Wouldn't be 'if (collider.Length <= 0)'?

Comment: sorry, it was supposed to be "0", I changed it in an edit a few minutes after posting

Comment: I don't know how your tilemap is oriented but did you try `GetCellCenterWorld(new Vector3Int(x, 0, y))` instead?

Comment: unfortunately not. The co-ordinates of "tilePos" are coming up correct, as the objects are being moved to their intended locations, however, even though I also use "tilePos" each time I want an overlapSpheres, the spheres will only spawn in the bottom left. (I did check your suggestion just in case I had been stupid thouh)

Comment: am I missing something? Is there a function/method that I can use to move an overlapSphere to the desired location after I have created it?

Comment: C# != UnityScript. UnityScript is a JavaScript derivative created for Unity.

Comment: @CallumNesbitt no, OverlapShpere is resolved in a frame, if you want to move, you have to invoke it again with another coordinates